# define coordinates to locate textView

Tags: android, textview, position, padding, coordinate

I have a `RelativeLayout` within a `ScrollView`, I am trying to move the textView, move it down or to the right but I can not find the way.

I tried with:

```
valueTV.setPadding(200, 500, 40, 100);
```

But the textView does not change its place

Paste my code:

```
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
        valueTV.setText("try txtVw");
        valueTV.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( 30,20));
//      valueTV.setPadding(200, 500, 40, 100); //It doesn't work//
        layout.addView(valueTV);
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should do it in XML file and separate `UI` from application logic. Code is so cleaner and clearer. You can use `layout_marginTop`, `layout_marginBottom`, `gravity` etc.

Comment: I need to do it from the java code that I would add the Textview dynamically, so I can not do it from the XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will help you. try this.

```
TextView tv;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.rightMargin = //RIGHTMARGIN;
lp.leftMargin = //LEFT MARGIN;
lp.topMargin = // TOP MARGIN;
lp.bottomMargin =  // BOTTOM MARGIN;
layout.addView(tv, lp);
```

Comment: I've the next error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams. At line: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)      tv.getLayoutParams();

Answer (score 0):

U have to use the XMl file in the res to design,its more easy and comfortable to design when compare to designing using java code as u have done.
If u are using java code,make sure you enter corect coddinates as well as the size of tht textview is appropiate

Comment: The size of the textView already is I give it with setLayoutParams, but not be the way to locate the textView by Padding, or coordinates. I need to do it from the java code that I would add the Textview dynamically, so I can not do it from the XML